# Flask app exception during jwt.decode()

Tags: python, flask, jwt, decode

I get an exception in the following snippet, which constitutes part of an authentication decorator in my flask app:

```
try:
    token = jwt.decode(
            request.headers.get('Authorization'),
            secret,
            algorithms=['HS256'])
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

The exception being:

```
Invalid token type. Token must be a <class 'bytes'>
```

One of the test cases that causes this looks like:

```
resp = self.app.get('/api/1.0/environments',
                        headers={"key": "Authorization",
                                 "value": self.api_token,
                                 "description": ""},
                        content_type='application/json')
```

The exceptions occur even when content_type is removed, and appear only during unit testing.

The same decorator works fine when tested via a rest client such as postman, with the same authentication key.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check that the `Authorization` header is present and that `request.headers.get` does not return `None`? Some web servers (both IIS and Apache) remove the `Authorization` header from requests...

Comment: I did check that the headers were present, but the header structure was wrong, in that request.headers.get was returning None - didn't check that. Thanks for pointing it out! Silly brain freeze.